# UITableViewStylePlain with Opaque Header

Tags: uitableview

I implemented a UITableView with style UITableViewStylePlain. I am using a custom header view with a solid background color, which should be opaque. But the headers are not opaque, leaving the cells visible as they scroll under the header. I want to make the headers opaque, but I don't see how this would done.

Answer (score 5):

When table view is plain, it's visible if at least one of cells in its section is on the screen. So looks like table view sets a background view for header somewhere internally with some alpha. But you could set background view to a custom view and to set background to it then.

You could do this when you create a custom header view in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = ...
  header.backgroundView = [UIView new];
  header.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

  return header;
}
```

Or if you don't want to create a custom header view, then probably you could set the background in `tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:` fir the default header views.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who may be interested, the solution for this was simple, but not obvious. I tried different things before I came to something that worked. I knew it could be done, because I had seen it in at least one other app.

These involve using a custom header created by the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` delegate method.

**What Didn't Work:**

1) Setting the backgroundColor property of the parent view that was created in this delegate method. For some reason, this color is ignored when it is used for a custom header view.

2) I noticed that the subviews were not transparent, so I tried putting an intermediate view in between the parent view and the existing subviews. I set the background color of this view to a solid color. This was also ignored.

**What Worked:**

3) Setting the backgroundColor property with this code:

```
 [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage.png"]];
```

For some reason, a simple color wil not work, but a color created from an image does.

I'll leave this question open for another day, in case someone wants to explain what is going on here as far as how a custom header view is rendered. I didn't see anything in the documentation about this little detail, but I may have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same problem. The solution which did work was to sub class UITableViewHeaderFooterView and then override the drawRect...

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4:

just set the background color property of Tableview cell to white or any color you want. you can set it from story board itself.